# Terms filter on a list of not_analysed string

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose there is a mapping like this:

```
"keywords": {
  "type": "string",
  "fields": {
    "raw": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    }
  }
},
```

I wan't to get query like this:

```
Retrive all of documents that contain(exactly and phrase) "Blah Mlah" AND "Baw"
```

To following elasticsearch document for [term filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-terms-filter.html), I'm try like this:

```
    'query': {
        'filtered': {
            'filter': {
                'bool': {
                    'must': {
                          [
                             {
                                "terms": {
                                    "keywords": ["Blah Mlah", "Baw"],
                                    "execution": "and"
                                }
                             }
                          ]
                        }
                     }
                },
            },
        },
    },
```

but "execution:and" not work and it's will return like `or`.
Also i'm tried this:

```
 [
   {
      "term": {
          "keywords": "Blah Mlah"
      }
   },
   {
      "term": {
          "keywords": "Baw"
      }
   }
]
```

but it's not work on keywords field when i wan't to search two word keywords like `"Blah Mlah"`. How can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the query should be against `keywords.raw` since that is the [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html) that has not been analyzed

**Example Query in 1.x :**

```
 put test 

  put test/test/_mapping
{
   "properties": {
      "keywords": {
         "type": "string",
         "fields": {
            "raw": {
               "type": "string",
               "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

 put test/test/1
  {
    "keywords" : [ "Baw", "Blah Mlah"]
  }
put test/test/2
  {
    "keywords" : ["Baw"]
  }


post test/test/_search 
   {
       "query": {
          "filtered": {
             "filter": {
                "bool": {
                   "must": [
                      {
                         "terms": {
                            "keywords.raw": [
                               "Blah Mlah",
                               "Baw"
                            ],
                            "execution": "and"
                         }
                      }
                   ]
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

Results:

```
"hits": {
  "total": 1,
  "max_score": 1,
  "hits": [
     {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "keywords": [
              "Baw",
              "Blah Mlah"
           ]
        }
     }
  ]
```

}

**Example Query in  2.x :**

```
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "filter": [
            {
               "terms": {
                  "keywords.raw": [
                     "Blah Mlah"
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "terms": {
                  "keywords.raw": [
                     "Baw"
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I use 1.x syntax and `keywords.raw` search correct. but and filter not work and its return OR of two keywords result. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: which version of elasticsearch ?

Comment: strange i jsut tested on elasticsearch 1.7.2 and it works , see the edited example